# Formatting a TimeSpan object is always displaying 00 for milliseconds

Tags: c#, timespan

C# WinForms here.

I need to extract Seconds and Milliseconds from a similar string: "13.9" where 13 are Seconds and 9 Milliseconds.
To do this i use a String.Split() function and after i create a TimeSpan object with the corresponding values (suppose TimeString is "13.9"):

```
private TimeSpan TimeSplit(string TimeString)
    {
        var Seconds = Int32.Parse(TimeString.Split('.')[0]); //output 13
        var Milliseconds = Int32.Parse(TimeString.Split('.')[1]); //output 9
        var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, Milliseconds, Decimals);
        return ts;
    }
```

Now i need to use the TimeSpan to show formatted output:

```
TimeSpan TempTs = TimeSplit(output);
SetTextMP(TempTs.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff"));
```

I need to have an output like: hh:mm:ss.ff but in my try Milliseconds(ff) stay fixed to 0. I checked and they are there..

Comment: There is one Timespan.Seconds as well. you can use that directly rather than splitting the string.

Comment: I believe your issue is because 9 milliseconds amount to 0.009 seconds. Try running it with an additional f -> fff. It should show your number correctly then.

Comment: Use fff instead of ff

Comment: ff displays hundreds of a second

Comment: As stated by @Saragis fff is milliseconds, ff is hundreths of a second. Here's the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for future use.

Comment: @Pankaj yes, thanks...

Saragis, Barry is the right solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way a little trick to be able to use ff intead of fff (also works with f alone) is to multiply milliseconds:
    `var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, Seconds, (Milliseconds * 10));`

Comment: @ShawnWest That will give you unexpected side-effects when the number of milliseconds exceeds 99. 5s & 101ms will become 6s & 10ms, which will be formatted as 06.01.

Comment: @Saragis : Yes Sir. Anyway i use the TimeSpan to read a process output (command line). The TimeSpan reset at every output flush. Having a simple decimal in my strings i obtain max 9*100 = 900ms or in my case 9*10ms = 90ms then we never touch the seconds. Obviously noone must use the trick if plan to add or subtract with other TimeSpans, but this is not the case. Thanks for the feedback anyway, this 'trick' must be used only if someone have decimals to read from and not real milliseconds.

Comment: Edit: In my case (the question) i have exactly the point of view, i have Seconds and Decimals. It's the timespan that read it as milliseconds while they are not ;-) I just corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the issue here is because 9 milliseconds amounts to 0.009 seconds. Running it with format specifier fff displays the complete millisecond value.